# $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^r \over n^{r+1}}={1 \over 1+r}$

Tags: calculus

If $r\in\Bbb N$ then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^r \over n^{r+1}}={1 \over 1+r}$

How to prove above equality?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/riemann-sums-ab/definite-integral-as-the-limit-of-a-riemann-sum-ab/v/riemann-sums-and-integrals

Comment: You asked third question on same topic without any effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question works on the fact that limits of a summation is equal to an integral, i.e a Riemann sum.

The question can be written as
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac in\right)^r$$

This is equivalent to
$$\int_0^1 x^r dx$$

Which becomes $$\left[\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}\right]_0^1 = \frac1{r+1}$$

Comment: It'd be good if you tell the OP how to convert the summation into integral in case OP doesn't knows. Otherwise, it's well written.

Answer (score 1):

Interpret $\sum_{i=1}^n(1/n)(i/n)^r$ as a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 x^r\,dx$.